# Bootstrap Modal Form: Labels don't right-align/getting widths correct for in-line sections

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 3 modal form that uses mixed form-horizontal and form-inline classes. I've fiddled around with the column widths but can't seem to get the form just right.  There are two problems that I can't seem to get resolved:

1. The labels don't right align.
2. The State field is not the correct width.

My Html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2>Agents</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a id="addAgentButton" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add Agent</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="agentModal" data-bind="with:detailAgent" class="modal fade">

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body col-md-12">
                <form role="form" data-bind="submit: save">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="txtAgentName">Name: </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><input class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAgentName" type="text" data-bind="value:Name" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="txtAgentAddressLine1">Address 1: </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAgentAddressLine1" type="text" data-bind="value:Address1" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12 form-inline">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="txtAgentCity">City: </label>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAgentCity" type="text" data-bind="value:City" />
                        </div>

                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="txtAgentState">State: </label>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <select class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAgentState" data-bind="options: $root.states, value: State, optionsCaption:'Choose a state...'"></select>
                        </div>

                        <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="txtAgentZip">Zip: </label>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAgentZip" data-bind="value:Zip" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

My Javascript to show the modal:

```
$("#addAgentButton").on("click", function() {
            $("#agentModal").modal("show");
        });
```

My CSS:

```
.modal-dialog {
  width: 800px;/* your width */
}

#addAgentButton {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

[And here's the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Steve5877/YHVGs/)

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot how you want the desired outcome? Without a clear picture it's hard to understand what you need.

Comment: Here's a better description. If its still a question, I'll try to get a drawing this afternoon.  If you hit the Add Agent button in the fiddle and then expand the view panel, you'll hit a point where the form goes to inline for the city, state and zip.  At that point you'll see that the issues with labels and state input. Sorry, should have said that in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I hope I understood you correct. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHVGs/5/)

I had to change your inline-form html part a bit:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtAgentCity">City: </label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAgentCity" type="text" data-bind="value:City" />
    </div>

    <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-right" for="txtAgentState">State: </label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <select class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAgentState" data-bind="options: $root.states, value: State, optionsCaption:'Choose a state...'"></select>
    </div>

    <label class="col-md-2 control-lntZip text-right">Zip: </label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAgentZip" data-bind="value:Zip" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Just add the class `.text-right` to the `label` you want to be aligned right.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why .control-label isn't moving things right?

Comment: This just works for the standard horizontal-form setup. If you mix both styles you have to fiddle a bit to make it work.. ;)